# What's the difference between script function and code behind function?

Tags: asp.net

```
<script runat="server">

    Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        ' The first time the page loads,
        ' render the DefaultView.
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            ' Set DefaultView as the active view.
            MultiView1.SetActiveView(DefaultView)
        End If

    End Sub

    Sub LinkButton_Command(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs)
        ' Determine which link button was clicked
        ' and set the active view to
        ' the view selected by the user.
        Select Case (e.CommandArgument)
            Case "DefaultView"
                MultiView1.SetActiveView(DefaultView)
            Case "News"
                MultiView1.SetActiveView(NewsView)
            Case "Shopping"
                MultiView1.SetActiveView(ShoppingView)
            Case Else
                Throw New Exception("You did not select a valid list item.")

        End Select

    End Sub

</script>
```

what is difference between above code in(aspx) And if the same code in code behind(aspx.cs). Difference between function defined in  tag with runat="server" attribute and function defined in code behind...?

Answer (score 3):

```
 How to execute JavaScript Function From ASP.NET Code:
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="How_calljavascript_aspx_page.aspx.cs" Inherits="How_calljavascript_aspx_page" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">


    <title>Call JavaScript in asp.net page by C# on page load </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function MyFunction() {
            alert('this is javascript function run by C# code.');
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

execute JavaScript from code behind in asp.net:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class How_calljavascript_aspx_page : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("alert"))
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
                "alert", "MyFunction();", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Functionally there is no difference between these two approaches, both will work the same for you.

Page script is useful if you have a small server side code, so that you can embed that code in the page itself.

- But this will make things messier if the code is large.
- The page designers will have access to the page code here.

The code behind approach provides you a clear separation of HTML and asp or VB code. Thats all...no functional difference between two approaches.

Comment: Ok undrstnd. Thnx.. :-)